# Dynamically filtering @FetchRequest with SwiftUI using Bool - show true, false or both

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui

I have a list in SwiftUI in (ListView) that pulls data from Core Data. I would like to filter it dynamically. I have a fetchRequest like this:

```
init(filter: Bool) {        
    fetchRequest = FetchRequest<Transaction>(entity: Transaction.entity(), sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "income = %d", filter))
}
```

**Transaction** is a Core Data Entity with an Attribute **income** (Bool).

In ContentView I am calling ListView like this:

```
ListView(filter: incomeTypeFilter)
```

And I have 3 buttons to change filter (true or false which stands for true=income, false=expenses):

```
Button("Show income") {
        self.incomeTypeFilter = true
}

Button("Show expenses") {
    self.incomeTypeFilter = false
}

Button("Show ALL") {
    // I don't know how to show ALL items in the list. Both true and false.
}
```

**Buttons to show income and expenses work. They change self.incomeTypeFilter to be true or false. But how to change predicate to show ALL items? Both true and false?**

P.s. My code is based on this tutorial: [Dynamically filtering @FetchRequest with SwiftUI](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/dynamically-filtering-fetchrequest-with-swiftui)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of two fetch requests, one with a predicate and one without and determine which one to use by letting the parameter be optional

```
init(filter: Bool?) {
    if let filter = filter {        
        fetchRequest = FetchRequest<Transaction>(entity: Transaction.entity(), sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "income = %d", filter))
    } else { 
        fetchRequest = FetchRequest<Transaction>(entity: Transaction.entity(), sortDescriptors: [])
    }
}
```

So all would correspond to calling the init with nil

EDIT:

And later:
Make incomeTypeFilter var in ContentView optional:

```
@State var incomeTypeFilter :Bool? = true
```

And make SHOW ALL button like this:

```
Button("Show ALL") {
    self.incomeTypeFilter = nil
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Joakim, but I cannot manage to make it work. I have used your code, but I still don't know how to make this 3rd button to show ALL items. I assumed I need to make `Button("Show ALL") { self.incomeTypeFilter = nil }` but this just gives me error: 'nil' cannot be assigned to type 'Bool'. I don't know how to trigger this code in your `else` part.

Comment: OK, I can do it! :) Thanks for help! I just needed to make this var in ContentView optional too: `@State var incomeTypeFilter :Bool? = true` and Button worked the same as I expected. I will edit and update your answer. Thank you very much for help!